Receiving the automatic offer of a WPA2-Enterprise certificate on ANY Linux distro
On iOS, Windows, and MacOS, when you attempt to connect to a WPA2-Enterpise network, after you enter your credentials, it offers you the certificate, to install.
The same doesn't apply for any Linux distro, however.

I have tried on everything from Ubuntu to Kali.

Manually providing the certificate isn’t an option.

If relevant, the network uses PEAP, and mschapv2 as it's inner auth.



I have edited my question and updated it to "any Linux," because this doesn't just apply to Kali. Even Ubuntu, being considered the most 'user friendly' distro, there is no automatic offer.
Surely this is possible? Hours of research have still left me stumped.

Are you using Kali as an operating system?

@terdon no offence, but I assumed that was obvious… yes

It isn't really obvious since that isn't what Kali is for, so it is always odd and surprising when someone tries to misuse it as a regular OS. It isn't a regular OS, it's a professional pen-testing tool, and has no business being used as a regular OS. Please read the official Kali doc on this, as well as Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?.

@terdon Quite frankly I am a proficient Linux user (I even have experience with assistive administration,) and I know exactly what Kali is for. In fact I don’t even use it as a “main OS,” but for other purposes. I am usually quite competent with operating it, but this in particular I don’t know.

Fair enough. If you aren't using it as your regular OS, that makes more sense.

@terdon thanks for looking out for me, but I don’t misuse Kali, or at least by my definitions of use. And no, I am not using it for illicit purposes, either. I appreciate your concern.

This is a complete stab in the dark because my ignorance of WPA2-Enterpise is deep: have you tried visiting 192.168.1.1 (or whatever the network's equivalent is) in a browser? Does that present you with the certificate perhaps?

@terdon good idea, however I have already tried this. I guess the problem with Kali is that it’s very… small… and therefore not well documented.

Does this help?

@eyoung100 Thanks very much, that doesn't completely answer my question but it does really help! Cheers :D

I think this might help: how to view the wpa2 peap certificate offered by an AP
You can use these commands to obtain the .pem certificate offered by the AP.
Once you have that, you should be able to save it somewhere memorable and specify its path in your network manager configuration.

Thanks, but, and I could be wrong, in step 3 of that answer, connect, wouldn’t I need to already become authenticated by the AP? Or just attempt to connect, does it mean? Still a +1 for now.

Oh, I see what you’re suggesting… obtain the cert using that answer, and then afterwards, use it when attempting to successfully connect with network manager, along with the right creds etc.

I haven't tried it yet, but it sounds like a good idea, and I might as well award the bounty. Thanks for going to the effort.
